# Error in audioDetect.js of MIDI.js (midicube)

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api, midi, midi.js

I'm trying to use `MIDI.js` (because I don't know how else to play MIDI files smoothly when the browser tab is not in focus). More specifically, I'm trying a new version of `MIDI.js` called [`midicube`](https://github.com/mscuthbert/midicube).

Like in [the readme](https://github.com/mscuthbert/midicube), I do

```html
<script src="releases/midicube.js"></script>
<script>
MIDI.loadPlugin({
    // this only has piano. 
    // for other sounds install the MIDI.js 
    // soundfonts somewhere.
    soundfontUrl: "./examples/soundfont/",
    onerror: console.warn,
    onsuccess: () => {
        MIDI.noteOn(0, 60, 0);
    }
});
</script>
```

but I get

```
audioDetect.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')
    at s (audioDetect.js:38:22)
    at audioDetect.js:106:9
    at Module.$t (index.js:94:5)
    at mytest.html:3:6
s @ audioDetect.js:38
(anonymous) @ audioDetect.js:106
$t @ index.js:94
(anonymous) @ mytest.html:3
audioDetect.js:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild')
    at Audio.<anonymous> (audioDetect.js:36:8)
```

[Here](https://github.com/mscuthbert/midicube/blob/master/js/audioDetect.js#L32-L38) are the lines of code that cause the error. Am I doing something wrong or is `midicube` outdated in some way (latest commit 3 years ago)?

Comment: Perhaps you need to wait for the DOM to be ready before that code starts.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks, I wrapped the call to `loadPlugin` inside `setTimeout(() => { ` ... `}, 5000);` and now I'm getting different errors.

Comment: You can also handle a "DOMContentLoaded" event instead of using a timer. Usually simply moving your `<script>` tags to the very end of the body does the trick.